# How to remove linux capabilities?

Tags: kernel, log

One useful attribute for protecting log files is append-only. When this attribute is set, the file cannot be deleted, and writes are only allowed to append to the end of the file.

Obviously, an intruder who has gained root privileges could realize that file attributes are being used and just remove the append-only flag from the logs by running chattr -a. To prevent this,we’ll need to disable the ability to remove the append-only attribute. To accomplish this under Linux, use its capabilities mechanism.

To prevent a user from removing the append-only attribute from a file, we need to remove the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability.
How to remove this capability?

lcap utility was previously used for this purpose, but it is currently not available for ubuntu. Is there any other way to remove linux kernel capabilities?

Recounting: I success to install lcap_0.0.6 in ubuntu server 13.04 but after run the following command I get an error message:

```
sudo ./lcap CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABE
/proc/sys/kernel/cap-bound: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a a complete answer, but this may help understand what's going on.

From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html:

> **Capability bounding set prior to Linux 2.6.25**
>
> In kernels before 2.6.25, the capability bounding set is a system-
>   wide attribute that affects all threads on the system.  The bounding
>   set is accessible via the file `/proc/sys/kernel/cap-bound`.
>
> ...
>
> **Capability bounding set from Linux 2.6.25 onward**
>
> From Linux 2.6.25, the capability bounding set is a per-thread
>   attribute.  (There is no longer a system-wide capability bounding
>   set.)
>
> ...
>
> Removing capabilities from the bounding set is supported only if file
>   capabilities are compiled into the kernel.  In kernels before Linux
>   2.6.33, file capabilities were an optional feature configurable via
>   the `CONFIG_SECURITY_FILE_CAPABILITIES` option.  Since Linux 2.6.33,
>   the configuration option has been removed and file capabilities are
>   always part of the kernel.  When file capabilities are compiled into
>   the kernel, the `init` process (the ancestor of all processes) begins
>   with a full bounding set.  If file capabilities are not compiled into
>   the kernel, then `init` begins with a full bounding set minus
>   `CAP_SETPCAP`, because this capability has a different meaning when
>   there are no file capabilities.
>
> Removing a capability from the bounding set does not remove it from
>   the thread's inherited set.  However it does prevent the capability
>   from being added back into the thread's inherited set in the future.